# How to specify specific simulator for iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, visual-studio-code

i'm using visual studio code extension "[React Native Tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native)"
for running and building my react native application on simulator/device.

**Is there a way to specify simulator version for ex. "iPhone X Max" ?**

Currently when i start my build configuration for "Debug iOS", simulator "iPhone X" started automatically.

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Debug iOS",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "target": "simulator",
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Debug iOS device",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "target": "device",
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Debug Android",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "target": "simulator",
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    }

]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found solution.

Just added this

> "runArguments": ["--simulator", "iPhone Xs Max"]

to my launch configuration in launch.json

Here is how it looks now:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Debug iOS",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "target": "simulator",
        "runArguments": ["--simulator", "iPhone Xs Max"],
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Debug iOS device",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "target": "device",
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Debug Android",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "target": "simulator",
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    }

]}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can specify the simulator in the target key itself:

```
{
    "name": "Debug iOS",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
    "type": "reactnative",
    "request": "launch",
    "platform": "ios",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "target": "iPhone Xs Max",
    "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
}
```

Reference:

1. [VSCode React Native - GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/blob/master/SampleApplication/.vscode/launch.json)
2. [Setting up debug environment - Guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/blob/master/doc/debugging.md#debugging-on-ios-device)

Comment: Thanks, i've just posted solution i've found, you can check it bellow.
You configuration also will work but you have a mistake with name of iPhone simulator.
It should be "iPhone Xs Max" instead of "iPhone XS Max".

Comment: I'm marking your proposal as an answer because it’s the cleanest solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `--simulator "deviceName"` to `react-native run-ios` will let you choose the simulator.

That's for iPhone XS Max

```
react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone XS Max"
```

Comment: i'm not running my application from terminal. I'm asking how to specify that simulator version in launch.json config because i'm using React Native Tools.

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about but, anyway, why don't you open a terminal and run that command? Anyway, in VSCode you can open terminals with shortcut CTRL+^ and then run that command.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Anyway i found solution and will post it later.

Comment: Ok, I got it! I'm glad you found a solution

Comment: You can find it bellow.